# C++ pthread - how to return a value from thread function without waiting for finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I follow basic c++ tutorial for making multiple threads. I have draw loop, in frame I start  several threads. I don't wait for threads results with pthread_join, instead I continue drawing other objects. If appropriate object's draw frame detects that all threads are finished then I start "threadsFinished" function. As I write, I don't use pthread_join, instead, I like to write results to object which started these threads, in my case it is class Program. I accessed "Program" object via pointer in thread function, I can write results to this object here, but is it thread safe? Or should i use mutex with Program object?

here is my code:

```
void Program::onDraw(Matrix *matrix) {
    fireThreads();
    ....

    if (threadsStarted && threadsFinishedCount == NUM_THREADS) {
        threadsFinished();
    }
    ...draw other stuff, progress bar etc... 
}

void *Program::threadFunction(void *threadData) {
    thread_data *data = static_cast<thread_data*>(threadData);
    Program *program = static_cast<Program*>(data->owner);
    program->threadsFinishedCount++;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void Program::fireThreads() {
    if (threads == NULL) {
        threads = new pthread_t[NUM_THREADS];
        threadData = new thread_data[NUM_THREADS];
    }

    int rc;
    int i;

    threadsFinishedCount = 0;
    threadsStarted = true;

    for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ) {
        threadData[i].threadId = i;
        threadData[i].owner = this;

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, updateDB, (void *)&threadData[i]);

        if (rc) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

variables used are defined this way:

```
class Program {
...
    static void *threadFunction(void *threadId);
    bool threadsStarted;
    volatile int threadsFinishedCount;
...
}
```

Comment: Off topic but... your declaration of `volatile int threadsFinishedCount` suggests a misunderstanding as to the meaning of [`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv).  You probably want [`std::atomic<int> threadsFinishedCount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check better difference between volatile and atomic

Comment: @user1063364 unless you have the need to access hardware directly (eg IO ports) don't use `volatile`

Comment: I didn't know how to do it better. I am on c++98 just now. Maybe I can go to c++11 due atomic, but i must discuss it first. However, this is not my main problem

Comment: I will use mutex to protect this variable, it should be enough. I will use mutex for writing results in thread function

Comment: On `c++98` you need to check your compiler documentation as Standard C++ (98) has no concept of threads, memory synchronisation etc.

Comment: "am on c++98" -- sorry, but are you studying history? That's a standard from the last millenium which was superseded more than once. Current compilers support newer standards widely. Please don't waste your time! That said, concerning your question, there's a lot of vague descriptions. Extract and provide a [mcve] instead!

Answer (score 0):

> I can write results to this object here, but is it thread safe?

No, it is not thread-safe. In C/C++, if multiple threads access the same object concurrently and at least one of those accesses is a modification then you have a [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Data_race), which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Thread synchronization primitives, like mutexes and `atomic`, are exceptions to this rule, so you must use one of those to achieve thread safety.

Note that `volatile` is *not* an exception and never has been; concurrent access to `volatile` objects can still result in a race condition.